# JavaFX ActionEvent e only activating one time

Tags: java, javafx, javafx-8

I am currently trying to make a JavaFX program which moves an image upwards with the UP key, but it only works once after my initial key click. Anything after the first would not work.

```
game.setOnKeyPressed(e->begin()); 

public void begin() {
    birdView.setTranslateY(birdView.getTranslateX() - 100);
}
```

Comment: what is `game` here ?

Comment: Most likely a typo: You use `translateX` instead of `translateY` for the calculation of the new `translateY`. Since you never modify `translateX`, `translateX - 100` always yields the same result.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have multiple `Nodes` in the scene then make sure that all the nodes except the `birdView` have property `focusTraversable` set to `false`

```
focusTraversable="false"
```

Also, you a not recording the updated `TranslateX` state of `birdView` in any variable. Store updated `TranslateX` in some variable and increment it on the next key press event

```
private double x = 0; //instance variable

game.setOnKeyPressed(e->begin()); 

public void begin() {
    x += birdView.getTranslateX()-100;   
    birdView.setTranslateY(x);
}
```

Comment: You don't need to set the `focusTraversable` property to `false` unless the child consumes the `keyPressed` event. Actually this may prevent the program from working, if `game` itself cannot receive focus. In that case no event is delivered to any descendants of `game` or `game` itself, so the key handler is never invoked. BTW: The question does not mention using fxml at all. Setting the `focusTraversable` property looks a bit different in java code.